# PycharmでImportErrorが起きてしまうことについて

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

#### ImportErrorが発生してしまう

python初心者です. [pyperclip]というモジュールを使いたくて以下のコマンドでインストールをしたのですが，Pycharmでプログラムを実行すると`ImportError: No module named...`というエラーになってしまいます. どなたか解決策を教えていただけないでしょうか...?

```
install pip pyperclip
```

以下のコマンドでpyperclipがinstallできたのは確認済みです.

```
pip show pyperclip
Name: pyperclip
Version: 1.7.0
Summary: A cross-platform clipboard module for Python. (Only handles plain text for now.)
Home-page: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip
Author: Al Sweigart
Author-email: al@inventwithpython.com
License: BSD
Location: /Users/******/aconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

しかし，pycharmのpreferences->project interupterで使用できるモジュール(?)を確認したところ，pyperclipは見つかりませんでした．

また，ネットで解決方法を探りましたが，勉強不足で環境変数などの単語が出てくると全く分からなくなってしまいます...皆さんはそのようなプログラミング以前の知識はどのように身につけたのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

Anacondaはインストールされてますか？
もしされているようでしたら，もしかしたらAnacondaのパッケージの方に pyperclip がインストールされているのかもしれませんね．
Pycharm で interpreter の設定がデフォルトのままでしたら Anaconda ではなくPCにデフォルトで入っていたPythonが使われていると思うので，そこを変更すれば治るかと思います．要するに，PycharmとAnacondaを連携させてやればできます．やり方を以下に説明します．

File -> Setting -> Project:*** -> Project Interpreter

ここまで開いていただいて，右上のほうの歯車マークからAddを選択します．
Base Interpreterの右のほうにある「...」のマークを押していただいて，Anacondaの中にあるpythonファイルを選択します．
質問者様はPath的におそらくMacだと思われますので，Users\****\Anaconda3\bin\の中にpythonというバイナリファイルが潜んでるかと思います．

あとはOKを押してPycharmを再起動させてみてください．

もしこれでもできないようでしたらまたコメントください．

あと，環境変数などの知識に関してですが，こればっかりは正直経験だと思います．しかし，何も調べないままだと一生わからないままなので，わからない単語が出てきたらその都度ネットか何かで調べるくらいしか方法はないかもしれないです．．．
PCにいっぱい触れて，やりながら覚えていくのが一番の近道だと思います．

Comment: > `質問者様はPath的におそらくWindows` `pip show` の結果で、 `Location: /Users/...` と表示されているので、おそらくmacOSかと

Comment: 失礼しました、そうですね笑 ありがとうございます、訂正します。

Comment: +1: `Location: /Users/******/aconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages` と表示されているので確かに Anaconda の方へインストールされている気がします。